# create/update with Many to Many association in Node.js sequelize and PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am just creating or updating a table having a Many-to-Many association with another table like here:
Company <-> Industry <-> CompanyIndustryRelation.

Industry.js

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Industry = sequelize.define('Industry', {
    industry_name: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {
    timestamps: false,
    underscored: true,
    tableName: 'industry',
  });
  Industry.associate = function(models) {
    Industry.belongsToMany(models.Company, {
      through: 'company_industry_relation', foreignkey: 'industry_id'
    });
  };
  return Industry;
};
```

Company.js

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Company = sequelize.define('Company', {
    company_name: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {
    timestamps: false,
    underscored: true,
    tableName: 'company',
  });
  Company.associate = function(models) {
    Company.belongsToMany(models.Industry, {
      through: 'company_industry_relation', foreignKey: 'company_id'
    });
  };
  return Company;
};
```

CompanyIndustryRelation.js

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const CompanyIndustryRelation = sequelize.define('CompanyIndustryRelation', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
  }, {
    timestamps: false,
    underscored: true,
    tableName: 'company_industry_relation',
  });
  return CompanyIndustryRelation;
};
```

Currently I have the industry table already built like down below.
[image]

Industry array
industry = [ { label: 'Accounting' }, { label: 'Computer Science' } ]

CompanyName: 'ApolloIT'

I want to create a new company record with the given industry array and companyName.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please be more specific. It is better if you show an example of your data and what you want to achieve. With your relation I can only see `Company -> CompanyIndustryRelation <- Industry`. It's not clear what you want to create or update.

Comment: Dan, Thanks for replying! Just updated the question.

Comment: Dan, I have tried like this ```for (const i of industry) {
        const industryInstance = await Industry.findOne({ industry_name: i.label });
        await CompanyIndustryRelation.create({ company_id: company.id, industry_id: industryInstance.id });
      }``` But it's saying error ```"id" of relation "company_industry_relation" does not exist```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a simple way to create/update records with associations.

```
industries: [ 
 { value: 'Gaming', label: 'Gaming' },
 { value: 'Computer Science', label: 'Computer Science' } 
]
```

```
const company = await Company.create({
   company_name: companyName,
});

const industry = await Industry.findAll({
   where: { industry_name: { [Op.in]: _.map(industries, o => o.label) } }
});
await company.addIndustry(industry);
```

Please refer to here. https://sequelize.org/master/manual/advanced-many-to-many.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok. For what I can see, you are not doing your model definition right. In sequelize you create a model to relate to a database table, generally, this model has to be the same as the database table.

For Industry.js, your just defining the industry_name column, forgetting the **id**. The same goes for Company.js. If sequeliaze doesn't know the primary key... it wont work well.

In the case of CompanyIndustryRelation.js, generally, you don't need an **id** since the primary key (generally) is the related tables id. In this case it should be `industry_id` and `company_id`. Again, in the CompanyIndustryRelation.js there are no such fields.

When you are using a `n to n` relation, first you need to create the master tables. If you have:

company ---> CompanyIndustryRelation <--- Industry

Then first you have to create the `company` and the `industry` then the `CompanyIndustryRelation`.

In sequelize you can do (for create):

```
sequelize.transaction((t) => {// to make a rollback in case something goes wrong

    return Company.create(data_company, { transaction: t }).then((new_company) => {

        return Industry.create(data_industry, { transaction: t }).then((new_industry) => {

            //here goes the created ids, asuming your using autoincrement to create ids
            var data_relation = {industry_id: new_industry.id,company_id: new_company.id};
            return CompanyIndustryRelation.create(data_relation, { transaction: t }).then(()=>{

                return;// Everything OK you could return something here

// when there is an error, you have to throw it for the rollback to work
            }).catch(err => {throw err;});

        }).catch(err => {throw err;});

    }).catch(err => {throw err;});

}).catch(err => {
    // process error, then rollback
});
```

For the update, it is the same if you want to update in cascade, it is a good practice to use transactions in case something goes wrong in the middle.

There are other methods to use cascade updates or creates but everything is better if you use [transactions](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/transactions.html)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, btw. is there any way to use async-await ? And usage of the transaction is a must and mandatory?

Comment: In the link transactions is the sequelize manual and how to use it with await.

Comment: TypeError: _sequelize.default.transaction is not a function, where can I reference  sequelize?

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work, still saying ```column "id" of relation "company_industry_relation" does not exist```

Comment: I tried
`const t = await db.sequelize.transaction();
const company = await Company.create({
        company_name: companyName
      }, { transaction: t });

      for (const industry of industries) {
        const industryInstance = await Industry.findOne({ industry_name: industry.label });
        await CompanyIndustryRelation.create({ company_id: company.id, industry_id: industryInstance.id }, { transaction: t });
        await t.commit();
      }` But it doesn't work

Comment: Is there any way to solve the creating/updating with association by using `include` option? Like here`https://sequelize.org/master/manual/creating-with-associations.html#hasmany---belongstomany-association`?